# Trying to build a database lookup app, but I'm getting 'The entity type... requires a primary key to be defined', though it is defined in my DB

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, entity-framework-core

Would appreciate any help with this, as I have kind of run into difficulty with this module, after having discovered a bunch of homework I had overlooked. We are only 3 weeks in thankfully, but I really need to catch up.

Here is my code:

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using Week_2_exercise;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Linq;

namespace Week_2_exercise
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Northwind Shippers");

            Northwind db = new Northwind();
            IQueryable<Shippers> shippers = db.Shippers;

            foreach (Shippers s in shippers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}",
                                  s.ShipperID, s.CompanyName, s.Phone);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**Northwind.cs**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Week_2_exercise
{
    public class Northwind : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Shippers> Shippers { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) 
        {
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Northwind.db");
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename={path}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Shippers.cs**

```
namespace Week_2_exercise
{
    public class Shippers
    {
        public int ShipperID { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
    }
}
```

It builds fine, and isn't showing any error highlighting, but when i run it I get

> Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'Shippers' requires a primary key to be defined.

But the primary key is `ShipperID`, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXAxz.jpg).

I've looked at the solution we are provided with, and the first thing that really jumped out at me as it does not contain a `Shippers.cs` file at all. I don't understand why I have it but the solution doesn't, but I doubt that is what is causing the error. I just created mine when I was following the video tutorials along but seemingly it is not needed.

The other thing that strikes me is there is quite a bit of difference between my version of Program.cs and the solution version:

```
using System;

using UWS.Shared;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Linq;

namespace NorthwindShippers
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Northwind Shippers");

            string currentDir = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            string parentDir = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(currentDir).FullName;
            string pathDb = System.IO.Path.Combine(parentDir, "Northwind.db");

            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<Northwind>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename={pathDb}");

            using (var db = new Northwind(optionsBuilder.Options))
            {
                IQueryable<Shipper> ships = db.Shippers;

                foreach (Shipper s in ships)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{s.ShipperID}. {s.CompanyName} {s.Phone}");
                }
            }

            Console.Write("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I was particularly struck by this section being different from my version:

```
IQueryable<Shipper> ships = db.Shippers;

foreach (Shipper s in ships)
```

But when I try to update mine to match it, just throws errors for `Shipper` and `Shippers`, though `ships` appears to be valid.

I don't have any of those `string` lines either, but in [the video tutorial](https://youtu.be/-OjV0fTuDY0) he runs the query fine without any of those lines being entered, so I can't see they are needed.

One thing that really baffles me is I have

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="3.0.0" />
```

but the solution shows

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\NorthwindContextLib\NorthwindContextLib.csproj" />
```

I don't get that at all, because what is the point of the `NorthwindContextLib.csproj` file pointing to itself? There must be some reason for that line, but it just appears like a circular reference to my (probably faulty) understanding.

I got the following reply on another thread, which I am trying to implement:

> > But the primary key is ShipperID

> It is in the database because presumably you're doing db first - but EF isn't able to figure it out because the name doesn't follow the convention it expects. In your db context (`Northwind`) override `OnModelCreating` and tell EF explicitly what to do. Something like:

```
modelBuild.Entity<Shipper>().HasKey( x => x.ShipperId )
```

> Or else you can probably slap a [PrimaryKey] attribute on it

I could literally just copy-paste the entire solution, but that is clearly not going to teach me anything. Can anyone help me figure this out? TIA. (I am using Visual studio Code 1.53.2.)

Edit: I just saw the solution has a whole bunch of code in Northwind.cs that my version lacks. I'm finding it really confusing though because I don't see him entering any of this prior to him doing the simple database lookup in the video tutorials. Even though this is not assessed work I really don't want to start pasting in chunks of code from the solution without properly understanding what they are doing.

Solution code:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace UWS.Shared
{
    public class Northwind : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Shipper> Shippers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }

        public Northwind(DbContextOptions<Northwind> options)
          : base(options) { }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(
          ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
              .Property(c => c.CategoryName)
              .IsRequired()
              .HasMaxLength(15);

            // define a one-to-many relationship
            modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
              .HasMany(c => c.Products)
              .WithOne(p => p.Category);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
              .Property(c => c.CustomerID)
              .IsRequired()
              .HasMaxLength(5);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
              .Property(c => c.CompanyName)
              .IsRequired()
              .HasMaxLength(40);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
              .Property(c => c.ContactName)
              .HasMaxLength(30);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
              .Property(c => c.Country)
              .HasMaxLength(15);

            // define a one-to-many relationship
            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
              .HasMany(c => c.Orders)
              .WithOne(o => o.Customer);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
              .Property(c => c.LastName)
              .IsRequired()
              .HasMaxLength(20);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
              .Property(c => c.FirstName)
              .IsRequired()
              .HasMaxLength(10);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
              .Property(c => c.Country)
              .HasMaxLength(15);

            // define a one-to-many relationship
            modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
              .HasMany(e => e.Orders)
              .WithOne(o => o.Employee);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
              .Property(c => c.ProductName)
              .IsRequired()
              .HasMaxLength(40);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
              .HasOne(p => p.Category)
              .WithMany(c => c.Products);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
              .HasOne(p => p.Supplier)
              .WithMany(s => s.Products);

            // define a one-to-many relationship
            // with a property key that does not
            // follow naming conventions
            modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
              .HasOne(o => o.Shipper)
              .WithMany(s => s.Orders)
              .HasForeignKey(o => o.ShipVia);

            // the table name has a space in it
            modelBuilder.Entity<OrderDetail>()
              .ToTable("Order Details");

            // define multi-column primary key
            // for Order Details table 
            modelBuilder.Entity<OrderDetail>()
              .HasKey(od => new { od.OrderID, od.ProductID });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Supplier>()
              .Property(c => c.CompanyName)
              .IsRequired()
              .HasMaxLength(40);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Supplier>()
              .HasMany(s => s.Products)
              .WithOne(p => p.Supplier);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit2:

I have worked out at least part of the issue. In the solution there is

```
    public DbSet<Shipper> Shippers { get; set; }
```

but I had

```
    public DbSet<Shippers> Shippers { get; set; }
```

When I update mine I get

> The type or namespace name 'Shipper' could not be found

so clearly that is the next thing to fix.

Edit3: I appear to have solved the problem, though in all honesty this fix seems a bit crazy to me.

First of all I had to update Shippers.cs with `public class Shipper`, which seems very odd as I thought the class name should always match the file name.

Then I was able to do `public DbSet<Shipper> Shippers { get; set; }` in Northwind.cs and the following in Program.cs:

```
    IQueryable<Shipper> ships = db.Shippers;
                        foreach (Shipper s in ships)
```

I am especially puzzled that the solution did not contain any Shippers.cs file. I will definitely be asking teach about that.

Comment: Could you please cleanup and shorten your post? You first tell about issues with Shippers and Shipper and later you write that it's solved by now there's something else and then you have "some error messages I've never seen before"... if you would reduce the post to ONE single issue and shorten it as much as possible, others would have a chance to understand your problem (without having to invest hours)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **convention** that EF core follows to figure out the primary key is this: either the field in the C# class is called `Id` - or it's called `(entity)Id` - in your case, that would have to be `ShippersId`  since the class is `Shippers` - this is **different** from the `ShipperId` that you currently have.

As such, EF Core **will NOT** automatically detect any primary key column. You need to **either**:

- rename your column to `ShippersId` so that EF Core can automatically detect it
- decorate your column `ShipperId` with a `[Key]` annotation to indicate this is the primary key column

Or as you mentioned as "solution": if you rename your **class** to `Shipper`, then EF Core will now **automatically** detect `ShipperId` as being the primary key.